# RabbitMQ queue gets blank randomly with around 5K messages remaining

Tags: rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I have a queue to which a lot of messages are published (~10K). Connected to this queue are multiple consumers with the following code in codeigniter using the `php-amqplib` library

```
public function processQueue()
{
    // Make connection
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    // Make channel
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    // Declare queue
    $channel->queue_declare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, false);

    // PHP callable
    $callback = function ($msg) {

        //DO MESSAGE PROCESSING HERE

        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

    };

    $channel->basic_consume(AGENTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

    // While queue is empty, wait
    while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
        // Wait
        $channel->wait();
    }

    // Close channel and connection
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
}
```

The messages gets filled up and are simultaneously consumed by multiple such consumers. I've observed that with some 5-6k messages remaining (i.e. after consuming around 4-5k) messages, the queue suddenly gets empty with the consumers idling and waiting for more messages. Also, there is a sudden drop at this point in time in the total number of messages on the RabbitMQ Management web panel.

I've tried making the queue with the durable parameter but the problem seems to be the same. What could be the issue and its resolution?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Start off by providing the versions of the software you are using. Ideally you would provide steps to reproduce. Finally, the management UI and statistics data is on a 5-second interval so there is a chance "that sudden drop" is a batch of messages being consumed at the same point in time.

Comment: I am running RabbitMQ-server v3.3.5. The consumers have a prefetch count to set around 25 and there are max 5 consumers, so the 5k messages remaining have no chance of being consumed at once

Comment: "so the 5k messages remaining have no chance of being consumed at once" no, but they do have a chance of being consumed within a 5 second window. More than likely this is an application issue or a mis-understanding of how RabbitMQ works, not a problem with RabbitMQ itself. Version 3.3.5 is very, very old. You should upgrade both RMQ and Erlang. Again, there's not much more assistance that can be given without more information or a means to reproduce.

Comment: I've set a prefetch count